# Array reinitializes on push()

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, ngfor, event-binding

I have a shopping list array of ingredient objects stored in the parent component. The child component lets me input the arguments for a new ingredient and send it to the parent on a button click.

For some reason after the received object is pushed into the array, it briefly appears in the DOM but quickly the app reloads and the object disappears as and the array is reinitialized to contain default objects.

Child template:

```html
<input type="text"
       id="name"
       class="form-control"
       #nameInput/>  

<input type="number"
       id="amount"
       class="form-control"
       #amountInput/>

<button class="btn btn-success"
        type="submit"
        (click)="onAddIngredient()"
        >
            Add
</button>
```

The child component launches an output event as it should and emits a new ingredient object with entered argument values:

```
export class ListEditComponent {
  @ViewChild('nameInput') nameInputRef!: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('amountInput') amountInputRef!: ElementRef;

  @Output() ingredientAdded = new EventEmitter<Ingredient>();

  onAddIngredient() {

    const ingName = this.nameInputRef.nativeElement.value;
    const ingAmount = this.amountInputRef.nativeElement.value

    const newIngredient = new Ingredient(ingName, ingAmount);
    this.ingredientAdded.emit(newIngredient);
  }
}
```

The parent component:

```
export class ShoppingListComponent implements OnInit {
  ingredients: Ingredient[] = [
    new Ingredient('Apples', 5),
    new Ingredient('Tomatoes', 5),
  ];

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  onIngredientAdded(newIngredient: Ingredient) {
    this.ingredients.push(newIngredient);
  }
}
```

In the parent template the list is generated using *ngFor:

```html
<app-list-edit (ingredientAdded)="onIngredientAdded($event)"></app-list-edit>
    <hr />
    <ul class="list-group">
      <a
         class="list-group-item"
         style="cursor: pointer"
         *ngFor="let ing of ingredients"
         >
        {{ ing.name }} ({{ ing.amount }})

      </a>
    </ul>
```

Comment: You mention the added item "quickly disappears as the app is reloaded", does this not answer your question? Unless you save the state of the app somewhere else everything will be reset after a reload.

Comment: I mean it reloads automatically briefly after the list in the DOM updates.

Comment: `type="submit"` Buttons with this type always submit the form they are in. If the `action` on that form is not specified, this usually results in a reload of the page.